# Same Port while test web app in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I m beginner in JMeter, I want to test web app which is deployed in apache and my apache port is 8080 and same as JMeter 8080, then showing below error, when try to start HTTP script recorder.

Could not create script recording proxy- port in use.choose another port:Address already in use:JVM_Bind

And when i have changed the port then nothing is recorded, KINDLY give me the solution.
Thanks in advance

Ankit Shukla

Comment: make them each other listening on a different port?

Answer (score 1):

Update the JMeter test script recorder to use the port 2020.

[image]

Then update your firefox browser as given below (Tools-->Options-->Network-->Settings)

[image]

Then 'start' the proxy server in HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder. You should be able to record now.

Comment: You get any error? Please share more information. Or you need to show your setup with images for better understanding of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update your port under global settings of HTTP(s) Script Recorder to different non used port and then save it. Click on Start button and Open browser(IE) and add proxy server as below

1. Tools > Internet options > Connections > LAN Settings
2. Select “proxy server”
3. Set Address=**localhost**; Port=**8080**(Configured Port)

Now, Record your browser actions(Just access the application u want to record and execute needed scenarios) and click on Stop of HTTP(s) Script Recorder.

U can see recorded steps under targeted controller. Thats All :)

Answer (score 0):

Close the debugger tool and try again. Ex: fiddler